# How can I sum values given a name across a data array?

Tags: excel, vba, grouping, sumifs

This would be fairly straightforward in SQL, but I'm stuck in Excel and am now not sure if I should use Pivots or a Macro in Excel.

Situation: I have two columns. One has a list of names or category types (for example: "Phones", "Tablets", "Computers", "Tablets", "Phones"). The second column has corresponding data in it--weekly units sold (for example: 5, 7, 3, 6, 5).

Ask: I would like to have the same two columns, only a unique name listed once in column one with the sum of its units sold in column two (i.e. in the example, to have a single column that lists once "Row 1: Phones and another column in row 1 that has total units "10", Row 2: Tablets and another column "13".

Sorry, a bit of a convoluted explanation without images. Anyhow, I know this can be done with several sumifs, but I need to do this across 20 data arrays for over 1000 different categories.

Comment: I would definitely use a pivot table for this. It is possible with VBA but, unless there is a compelling reason not to use a pivot, you're wasting your time. Do you need assistance creating a pivot table?

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable seems particularly suitable because it is very easy but also because if offers potential for a lot of additional analysis:

[image: SO31435234 example]

Here I have selected the whole of the two columns (hence `(blank)` in the PT) so additional entries may be continued below those already there - additions though will not be included in the PT until it is refreshed (three clicks).

For example, if the two entries each for `Phones` and `Tablets` are because each sale is recorded individually (or by salesperson etc) then switching `Sum of` to `Count of` (or just adding the latter) would show the number of sales (ie some multiple), rather than the number of units sold.

You mention "weekly units" - record the date of sale as an additional column and include it in the PT and the rows in the PT may be grouped by week - and/or month and/or year etc. It is also easy to display maximums and minimums - and there are very many more options, quick to set up and very quick to calculate.

The order can be changed (eg `Phones` put first) but defaults to alphabetic ascending.

However, I may be misinterpreting *another column in row 1*.